# HTTPS URL is redirect on First Configraion

Tags: apache, ssl

When i am hit https://subdomain2.example.com then pages are called form https://subdomain1.example.com but when i am hit sub2.example.com without HTTPS then it working fine below is my ssl.config..Give me any suggestion for below. what is an issue in my config

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
```

Below is my SSL Configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  subdomain1.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /Path/sub1
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ServerCertificate2017.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/keyw2017.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/Path/sub1">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  subdomain2.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /Path/sub2
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ServerCertificate2017.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/keyw2017.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/Path/sub2/">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In This Configuration Need to add Virtual Host Name in SSL Config then it will work as per the configuration other wise it will consider only first configuration..
Below is the code..

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

## OR

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443
```